# Moving a bound ZMQ socket to another process

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I have a Python program which spawns several other Python programs as subprocesses. One of these subprocesses is supposed to open and bind a ZMQ publisher socket, such that other subprocesses can subscribe to it.

I cannot give guarantees about which tcp ports will be available, so when I bind to a random port in the subprocess, my main program will not know what to tell the other subprocesses.

Is there a way to bind the socket in the main process and then somehow pass the socket to my subprocess? Or either some other way to preregister the socket or a standard way to pass the port information from the subprocess back to my main process (stdout and stderr are already used by other data)?

Just checking for a free port in the main process and passing that to the subprocess is not really optimal, because this could still fail if the socket is being assigned in the meantime. Also, since my program should work on Unix and Windows, I cannot really use ipc sockets, which would otherwise solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The simplest is to create a logic for a pool-of-ports manager
 <sub>( rather avoid attempts to share / pass `ZeroMQ` sockets to / among other processes )</sub>

One may create a persistent, a-priori known, **`tcp://A.B.C.D:8765`**-transport-class based **`.bind()`** access-point, exposed to all client processes as a port-assignment service, to which client processes **`.connect()`**, handshake in whatever manner is needed to proof an identity/credentials/purpose/etc and **`.recv()`** in a coordinated manner one actually free messaging/signalling-service port number, that is system-wide guaranteed to not be used at the very moment / until returned to the port-manager ( a rotating pool of ports is centrally managed, under your code-control, whereas all the sockets, created locally in the distributed process(es)/thread(s) `.connect() / .bind()`-ing to the pool-manager announced port#, and thus will still remain, and ought remain, consistently within `ZeroMQ` advice, not to be shared per-se ).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any particular reason (except maybe transaction overhead) that the manager has to assign the ports? As compared to having a particular service taking a free port when binding and then advertising it to the manager.

Comment: Well, if the process, that is to become a **`PUB`** provider knows it's local eco-system conditions and announces any/all locally verified to be feasible `ip-address:port#`(s) to the central pool-of-ports Manager in their initial handshaking & service notification, sure the pool could be created dynamically on-the-fly. I am just used to more rigid resources planning with latency avoidance and with pre-allocated resources' planning rather than paying the penalty of resolving collisions once lazy evaluation strikes into an empty pool-of-resources or into a collision on a resource unavailable.

Comment: There are also some hacky preferences on some port#-s, that have faster kernel-side handling latencies than other port#-s on the same O/S, so more details and more reasons to plan & pre-allocate resources into a pool-of-ports Manager, if a **high availability** and/or **fair-handling policies** are to be granted and inspected / validated for a certification authority.

Comment: Thanks again. Indeed, for a high-availability system, I might want to configure it differently. My current use case, though, is to be able to run each main program potentially with several instances (as a normal user on their machine) at the same time and have each process spawn its subprocesses and be able to communicate without much pre-configuration for each instance. Performance is not too much of an issue, I just want to avoid race conditions as much as possible.